# Build string method using complex type Entity Framework ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6

I had to use Entity Framework to equip an advanced search to my website application.

The model is generated from the database and has own entities but has some complex stored procedure that returning mixed columns.

To clarify, I have a `customer` entity with own columns but I want to use complex `customer_Fetch_List_Result` that is imported from the database to implement my advanced search.

```
using (DbModel db = new DbModel())
{
     var query = db.customer_Fetch_List(ViewState["Gym"].ToString(), 0).AsQueryable();

     if (chbFname.Checked)
     {
         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtcFName.Value))
         {
            query = query.Where(x => x.cFName.Contains(txtcFName.Value));
         }
     }

     if (chbLname.Checked)
     {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtcLName.Value))
        {
           query = query.Where(x => x.cLName.Contains(txtcLName.Value));
        }
     }

     if (chbGender.Checked)
     {
        if (ddlGender.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            query = query.Where(x => x.cSex == int.Parse(ddlGender.SelectedValue.ToString()));
        }
     }

     if (chbStars.Checked)
     {
         query = query.Where(x => x.stars == rating.Value);
     }

    var queryFinal = query.Select(q => new
                                       {
                                            q.cFName,
                                            q.cLName,
                                            q.cSex,
                                            q.aId,
                                            q.cId,
                                            q.stars
                                       });

   string output = Build_Customer_List(queryFinal); // ??
}
```

At last I want send queryFinal to

```
public string Build_Customer_List(queryFinal)
```

to generate a html string contains queryFinal details, but I can't find how implement `Build_Customer_List` function.

Thanks in advance for any tips and advice.

**Update #1**

I tried to implement `Build_Customer_List(queryFinal)` as follows:

```
 public string Build_Customer_List(IQueryable<customer_Fetch_List_Result> query)
 {
        string post = "";

        foreach (var item in query)
        {
            string narrow = Build_String.Get_Stars(item.stars.ToString());
            string subject = item.cFName + " " + item.cLName;
            post += "<a  href='#' class='list-group-item'><span class='narrow'>" + narrow + "</span><i class='fa fa-fw fa-comment'></i> <span>"
                      + subject + "</span></a>";
        }

        return post;
}
```

But I can't call `Build_Customer_List` - this was my attempt:

```
string post = cls.Customer_List(queryFinal.ToList<customer_Fetch_List_Result>());
```

OR

```
string post = cls.Customer_List(queryFinal);
```

Comment: Down vote. 1. Show us an example ouput with all the inputs. 2. Show us your attempt in doing so, even if it's a bad one.

Comment: Ok, I updated my post that mentioned the ways I tried.

Comment: You don't tell us the errors you are getting -- that should make the problem clear.  You problems have to do with not using concrete types.   replace var with an actual variable type (eg `List<customer_Fetch_List_Result>`)

Comment: I tried Both IEnumerable<customer_Fetch_List_Result> and  List<customer_Fetch_List_Result> as parameter but system error that : anonymous type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you need to build an external model with an `IQueryable` public method to returning data as `IQueryable` as following:

```
 public class customerComplex
{
    public string cFName { get; set; }
    public string cLName { get; set; }
    public int cSex { get; set; }
    public string aId { get; set; }
    public string cId { get; set; }
    public int stars { get; set; }

    public IQueryable<customerComplex> GetValues()
    {
        return new List<customerComplex>().AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

Indeed, I don't know what the data-types are exactly of your data model, but we assume I guess right. know you can use the custom model `customerComplex` to get select data from your `linq` query as following
:

```
var queryFinal = query.Select(q => new customerComplex
            {
                cId = q.cId,
                cFName = q.cFName,
                cLName = q.cLName,
                cSex = q.cSex,
                aId = q.aId,
                stars = q.stars
            }).ToList();
```

At last, you need to send the  `queryFinal` to a function that you mentioned it. we assume you function is  Customer_List(?). I defined this function in another class as following:

```
public string Customer_List(IEnumerable<customerComplex> query)
{
    string post = "";
    if(query.Count() > 0)
    {
        foreach (var item in query)
        {
            string name = item.cFName + " " + item.cLName;
            post += "<p>" + name + "</p>";
        }
    }
    return post;
}
```

Now, You can call `Customer_List()` and sent the `queryFinal` as folloing code:

```
string post = cls.Customer_List(queryFinal.AsEnumerable());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! could you please write your answer in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59401825/how-to-use-complex-type-in-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-web-application  post too? because I looking for an example of how to use complex type in select status.

Comment: Ok, If it's helping people why not.

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem, read up on c# anonymous types

```
q => new
    {
        q.cFName,
        q.cLName,
        q.cSex,
        q.aId,
        q.cId,
        q.stars
   });
```

Remove new, and if needed create a new type to hold this, adding back in new with

```
new MyNewType {.. };
```

THen use this type in your method

Comment: can't do that, system throws an error: Cannot initialize type 'customer_Fetch_List_Result' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Comment: Then add a ToList() to the end of the query and change the signature of the receiving method to List.

Comment: I have an error on q => new customer_Fetch_List_Result{ q.cFName,
        q.cLName,q.cSex,q.aId,q.cId,q.stars   });

Comment: I get that! Make the variable queryFinal a list of customer_Fetch_List_Result by adding ToList  here }).ToList();

Comment: sorry, there isn't such an option there. but I can add }).ToList(); if I use simple q => new but Build_Customer_List throws that old error

Comment: As I said above, you need to convert Build_Customer_List to receive a list collection. There is no need to hold the connection open at this point as you are done querying the DB. Just about any object can be stored in a list, even just the one. This will work.with the correct syntax.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204561/discussion-between-gerryfc-and-reza-paidar).

Comment: have you considered using a partialView result?